# How to tell Docker client location of Notary Server?

Tags: docker

I have a private Docker registry and recently setup a Notary server on a different Linux host.  Is it possible to have the registry on one Linux host and the Notary server on another?  I can't find anyway of telling the Docker client where to look for the Notary server ... it seems to assume it's on the same server as the registry.

tx!

Comment: Not familiar with Notary in docker. Do you mean, you are trying to pull images off from your Notary server? If yes, probably worth having a look at the `config.json` on ~/.docker directory and change the url of it to point to your server.

Comment: Not images, rather cryptographically signed metadata corresponding to those images.

Answer (score 1):

Try pointing `DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST_SERVER` from your docker client to point to the notary server IP address - that should do the trick.

Please let us know either here or on github.com/docker/notary as an issue if you have more questions :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of doing it. The first is to define it in the Notary CLI config file **config.json** as follows:

```
{
        "remote_server": {
                "url": "https://notary-server:4443"**,
                "root_ca": "root-ca.crt"
        }
}
```

The second is to define it as an environment variable:

```
export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST_SERVER=https://notary-server:4443
```

We assume that notary-server is defined in `/etc/hosts` next to its ip:

```
<IP-HOST> notary-server
```

Saludos.